# Flex-shrink not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm starting to work with flexbox, and, in order to understand `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`, I used a simple program that displays two blocks and makes them take up the whole width using `flex-grow: 2` in one of them and `flex-grow: 1` in the other.

If I check the following line in the console: `$(".one").width() === $(window).width() /3` it returns true. So far, so good.

The problem appears when I reduce the window size, because as soon as I do this the same line in the console (`$(".one").width() === $(window).width() /3`) starts returning false.

I know the default value for `flex-shrink` is `1`. Wouldn't that mean that the proportions between both blocks would be maintained (since they are both being shrunk by the same amount)? Can anyone explain why this result happens?

Here's my code:

```css
* {
  font-family: verdana;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="box one"></div>
    <div class="box two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like it's working to me. The widths are off by a fraction of a pixel on resize at most. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJrpWN

Comment: @Michael It seems to me that the more I shrink it, the less the difference between the width of the two blocks

Comment: if you `parseInt()` the values, it's always true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`flex-shrink` is designed to distribute *negative* free space in the container.

In other words, it only works when flex items are big enough to overflow the container.

You're not having that problem here. There is no negative space. Therefore, I don't believe `flex-shrink` is having any effect on your layout.

`flex-grow` is consuming the *positive* free space and seems to be working fine.

You would need to set a `flex-basis` or add content to the items to put `flex-shrink` in play.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property

Comment: Then how does the browser resize the elements when I manually resize the window?

Comment: That's got nothing to do with `flex-shrink`. You're reducing / expanding the width of the container, which is decreasing / increasing the space in the container, and `flex-grow` is adjusting accordingly.

Comment: Then what does `flex-shrink` do? (I'm sorry if I'm being annoying but I'm really new at this and I'm trying to understand as much as I can)

Comment: Here's an explanation for `flex-shrink`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34753491/3597276

Answer (score 14):

While not relevant to your question it might be worth noting:

> `flex-wrap` takes precedence over `flex-shrink`, unless the item is wider than the container.

- So if you have flex-wrap enabled and you're expecting two items to shrink to fit side by side on a single row they won't, they'll wrap first even if there's plenty of shrink-potential.
- If the item is wider than the parent container it can't wrap so it will shrink if it can.
- You'd have to solve this with min/max widths, make the initial size smaller (this is probably the best way) or creating a new parent container without flex-wrap.

See also [Is there any use for flex-shrink when flex-wrap is wrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868000)

Answer (score 2):

This is related to float calculations. Your flex code is working perfectly fine, the problem arises from the arithmetic operation, where the width of the container might not perfectly divide to 3, so the result will be a floating number which might or not be rounded to the closest number, so that's why width of your first flexbox item might not be equal to width / 3 because of that rounding.

Tested with Chrome Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#article-header-id-13

They suggest using the shorthand `flex: [number];` because it intelligently sets the default `flex-shrink` to `0`. Just because the default for `flex-shrink` is `1` doesn't mean that `1` is what you want. I haven't been using flexbox that long, but I've yet to come across a scenario in which I've had to specify a `flex-shrink`. `0` has been working for me thus far. Maybe somebody else can provide a scenario for using it.

## TLDR

Use `flex` attribute instead of `flex-grow`